# Make aSCNParticle's orientation match surface/vertex release

Tags: scenekit, particle-system

Is it possible to make particles being released from the surface of a geometry object (or from its vertices) push them out at an angle reflective/representative of the direction of travel?

eg. If the emitter object is a cube, and particles are moving out from each of the cube's 6 faces, the particles face exactly as the face that they're coming "off" from.

I've only been able to get them to move out correctly from the faces/vertices, but all the particles are aligned to the camera, screen or "free", in all cases they're essentially only facing one direction, not the six that they could/should if they each took on the angle of their origin and direction of travel from the faces/vertices of the cube.

What I want, is something like this behaviour from the particles emitting from the object (a cube in this example, but the principles the same for any kind of object).

[image]

EDIT:: above is just an example. 
Imagine this on a much grander scale, not like the below, but it will give you somewhat of an idea of the goal, though even MORE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 6 emitters with orientation mode set to "SCNParticleOrientationModeFree" and set it to local=YES. then control the orientation with the node that own the emitter.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say this. This is only an example of the problem i'm trying to solve, quickly sketched up. The real problem I'm trying to solve involves MUCH more than 6 angles. hence the attempt to find out how to do it from one source.

Comment: Edited question to make the objective and reason for the desire to do this with one emitter more clear.

Comment: Is there any chance this could be added as a feature request, and be possible?